# I cant acces to data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have the following problem: When I print the value of the shells variable inside the deleteRows function, it prints an empty object, but when I print it outside (first console.log) it prints the array correctly.  What is this about? I call the function by deleting a value.

I try make arrow function how you see in the code.

```
import React from 'react';
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';  //verrificacion de tipos
import MUIDataTable from 'mui-datatables';
import columns from '../Objects/columns';

const axios = require('axios');

function SimpleTable(props) {
  const { datos } = props;
  const shells = datos.map(
    dato => Object.values(dato),
  );
  console.log({shells})

  const deleteRows = (RowsDeleted) => {
    const ids = RowsDeleted.data.map(d => d.dataIndex);
    // const idsToDeleted = ids.map(d => shells[d][9]);
    console.log({shells})
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/eliminado',
      data: RowsDeleted,
    });
  }

  const options = {
    filterType: 'dropdawn',
    responsive: 'stacked',
    onRowsDelete: deleteRows,

  };

  // console.log(shells)
  return (

    <MUIDataTable
      title="NutsForShells"
      data={shells}
      columns={columns}
      options={options}
    />
  );
}

// SimpleTable.propTypes = {
//   classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
// };

export default (SimpleTable);
```

Comment: Why do you wrap shells in curly braces when you print it?

Comment: Just to try. Anyway without curly braces doesnt work either.

Answer (score 2):

By going through this [conversation](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/issues/27) what I found is, we cannot use data from outside in `callback` of `mui-datatables`.

From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-datatables),

> **onRowsDelete** - Callback function that triggers when row(s) are deleted. function(rowsDeleted: object(lookup: {dataindex: boolean}, data: arrayOfObjects: {index, dataIndex})) => void OR false (Returning false prevents row deletion.)

When you click to delete the row, you get rows to delete as well as complete data array. So your `deleteRows` function should take second argument which is a data array,

```
const deleteRows = (RowsDeleted, data) => {
    const ids = RowsDeleted.data.map(d => d.dataIndex);
    // const idsToDeleted = ids.map(d => shells[d][9]);   //This is possibly this, ids.map(d => data[d][9]) 
    console.log(data)  //Now you will get data
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/eliminado',
      data: RowsDeleted,
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ravi, this really help me :D

Comment: i try this and data is undefined.